# Getting Last Row Of Column - Excel Javascript

Tags: excel, office-js

I have the following code, which I expected would return `5` for `rowCount` for range `A1:A5` but it returns the `UsedRange` `lastrow` even when I have "filtered" to a subrange.

I tried using `ws.getColumn(0)`, but this threw an error.

How I can get the last row of column A without syncing the entire used range?

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var rng = ws.getRange("B1:B10")
rng.values = "B"
var rng = ws.getRange("A1:A5")
rng.values = "A"
await context.sync()
var col_one_rng = ws.getUsedRange(true).getColumn(0)
col_one_rng.load(['rowCount'])
col_one_rng.select() //Selects "A1:A10"
await context.sync();
var rowCount = col_one_rng.rowCount
console.log('rowCount:' + rowCount) //10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead... get the range for column A and then get the usedRange for that range:

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
ws.getRange("B1:B10").values = "B";
ws.getRange("A1:A5").values = "A";

var col_one_rng = ws
  .getRange("A:A")
  .getUsedRange(true)
  .load(['rowCount']);

col_one_rng.select(); // Selects "A1:A5"

await context.sync();

console.log('rowCount:' + col_one_rng.rowCount) // 5
```